# How do i use regexp with parameters on java-Mysql select query?

Tags: java, mysql, regex, concatenation

I want to select records from a database by many parameters

I tried to combine columns with concat and use regex

I can run this code but I want to use real parameters instead of 'NAME' and '1100'

```
String sorgu = 
    "Select per.* "
    + "from per_kimlik_bilgileri per"
    + " where  "
    + "concat"
    + "(pkb_tc_no, '/' , pkb_ad , '/' , pkb_soyad , '/' , 
   pkb_sicil_no , '/' , pkb_gorev_yeri , '/' , pkb_unvan_k , '/'"
    + " , pkb_gorev_k , '/' , pkb_istihdam_tipi ,'/', pkb_gor_drm) "
    +  "REGEXP   'NAME|1100'  " ;
```

`

I tried this way but it did not work

```
String sorgu = 
    "Select per.* "
    + "from per_kimlik_bilgileri per"
    + " where  "
    + "concat"
    + "(pkb_tc_no, '/' , pkb_ad , '/' , pkb_soyad , '/' , 
    pkb_sicil_no , '/' , pkb_gorev_yeri , '/' , pkb_unvan_k , '/'"
    + " , pkb_gorev_k , '/' , pkb_istihdam_tipi ,'/', pkb_gor_drm) "
    +   "REGEXP   '"+id+"' | '"+name+"'  " ;  `
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using concatenation of parameters for your prepared statements. Rather prefer using placeholders by question marks, and substitutions by `preparedStatement.setString()` especially against injection

```
....
PreparedStatement stmt = null;
try {
     String sorgu = 
    "Select per.* from per_kimlik_bilgileri per where  concat(pkb_tc_no, '/' , pkb_ad 
    ,'/' , pkb_soyad , '/' , pkb_sicil_no , '/' , pkb_gorev_yeri , '/' , pkb_unvan_k , '/'
    , pkb_gorev_k , '/' , pkb_istihdam_tipi ,'/', pkb_gor_drm) REGEXP ?|?  " ; 

    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sorgu);

    preparedStatement.setString(1, name);
    preparedStatement.setString(2, val);

    ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
    ......
```

Comment: Thank you, but it gives syntax error.  when i run preparedstatement.setString(1,name) it gives  Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).

Comment: well, right dear @NahitÖzçepni, we need to get rid of single quotes for `REGEXP` expression's pattern.

Comment: I rid single quotes arround the question marks and put arround | .Like that  (REGEXP ? '|' ?) And it's finally worked. Thank you again

Comment: @NahitÖzçepni you're welcome dear citizen. Kindly could you accept as the answer as it seeming to help.

Answer (score 0):

change last line to

```
+   "REGEXP   '"+id+"|"+name+"'  " ;
```

the `'` makes syntax error.